# Why is my text mesh text always in the back layer when seen in camera? (unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, offset

I have a text mesh text and I put it on top of a sprite. It is seen on top of the sprite in the scenes but when I play it in the game I can't see it. I tried changing the offset Z but it doesn't work. My camera's position.z is -10. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the camera's position to -10 will not do the trick. Here is a relevant post: [Unity3D: put 3D objects above GUI surface](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/unity3d-make-3d-objects-over-gui-surface/)

If you sprite is rendered using OnGUI() function, you can add your own camera (in addition to the main camera), follow the steps:

1. Add a new camera, name it “Camera4GUI” (or whatever you name),  in the Inspector, set the  parameters for this camera:
    Layer: background
    Clear Flag: Depth only
    Depth: -1
2. Select the main camera, in the Inspector, set the below parameters for this camera:
    Clear Flag: Depth only
    Culling Mask: (Everything other than background) Mixed
    Depth: 0
    Uncheck GUI Layer checkbox

Snapshots of this approach can be found [here](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/unity3d-make-3d-objects-over-gui-surface/).

[image]
[image]
[image]